# Is there a name for this concurrency pattern?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

The problem: we have critical path code that should never block. In many places it relies on configuration data, or similar, infrequently updated data from an external source.

When we need to reload configuration data, or refresh data from an external source, we don't want to lock access to that data and potentially block the critical path threads.

The solution: move the data in question to its own class. Use a background thread to fully perform the reload and validate the data. Then, when its ready, overwrite the old data reference with the new one.

This reference must be volatile to ensure visibility to all threads.

As long as its not imperative that the critical path code *always* have the most recent data available, this works great, with the absolute minimum performance impact (all data goes through a volatile ref).

The real question is, **is there a name for this concurrency design pattern**?

The language in question is Java, but I think this applies to most that support a shared-memory concurrency style of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to conclude that **there is no well-known name for this pattern**.

The concepts from clojure map cleanly to what I've described here, but *Ref* and *Identity* aren't sufficiently descriptive for a design pattern name in Java. Thanks to @Thiago for pointing these out though.

Thanks also to @Ed for pointing out that *double buffering* graphics and hardware is a very similar concept, but again it doesn't work as a design pattern name in Java.

For my purposes, I'm going to use something along the lines of **Atomic Build and Swap** with coworkers so that we can have a handle for this frequently occurring design.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it looks like a atomic reference to a Value Object

Value Object is a persistent object. It just represents a value, i.e. it represent a value from the moment you call the constructor to the end of it's life (no state change). Being a Value Object it is automatically Thread-safe.

The atomic reference to it is just a central point to get access to the last version of the Value Object.

The Clojure language call it a "ref".

I've found a blog post about a design pattern, in GoF form, that looks like what you want:
http://tobega.blogspot.com/2008/03/java-thread-safe-state-design-pattern.html

**EDIT:**

Rich Hickey (creator of Clojure) define it as Identity: "A putative entity we associate with a series of causally related values (states) over time".

Source: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey

Comment: Java has an AtomicReference class to support this pattern though `volatile` does the same thing if you never need to check for null - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281132/java-volatile-reference-vs-atomicreference

Comment: AtomicReference has some advantages like atomic compareAndSet operation. Very useful if, for example, the next version of the ValueObject depends on it's previous version. Using CAS correctly you can guarantee a linear timeline.

Comment: Agreed, this is basically a Value Object. I typically don't need AtomicReferences because compare-and-swap isn't usually required.

In clojure, a ref would probably carry all the meaning I need, but isn't a suitable handle for this pattern in java.

Perhaps I should make up a name, something like Volatile Value Ref, or Versioned Value Ref.

Answer (score 2):

Could [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Buffering#Double_buffering) be the term you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same concept. I just wish the term double buffering fit well into the context of concurrent programming. Maybe I should call this Build and Swap

Comment: Agreed - about the term being "wrong" - to the extent that I feared you wouldn't even recognize it conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do high-performance locking. This just sounds dangerous. Anyway, you'll want to take a copy of the data -- while locked -- unlock it, then work on that data.

Comment: I don't think this applies, the data in question is effectively immutable after its been prepared. Setting the volatile reference to it will make it safely visible to other threads.