# HashMap and visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

[HashMap's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) states:

> if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

I built a sample code that, based on the specification, is supposed to fail almost immediately and throw a ConcurrentModificationException;

- It does fail immediately as expected with Java 7
- but it (seems to) always work with Java 6 (i.e. it does not throw the promised exception).

Note: it sometimes does not fail with Java 7 (say 1 time out of 20) - I guess it has to do with thread scheduling (i.e. the 2 runnables are not interleaved).

**Am I missing something? Why does the version run with Java 6 not throw a ConcurrentModificationException?**

In substance, there are 2 Runnable tasks running in parallel (a countdownlatch is used to make them start approximately at the same time):

- one is adding items to the map
- the other one is iterating over the map, reading the keys and putting them into an array

The main thread then checks how many keys have been added to the array.

**Java 7 typical output** (the iteration fails immediately):

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   MAX i = 0

**Java 6 typical output** (the whole iteration goes through and the array contains all the added keys):

> MAX i = 99

**Code used**:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int SIZE = 100;
        final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(1, 1);
        map.put(2, 2);
        map.put(3, 3);
        final int[] list = new int[SIZE];
        final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Runnable put = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    start.await();
                    for (int i = 4; i < SIZE; i++) {
                        map.put(i, i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable iterate = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    start.await();
                    int i = 0;
                    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
                        list[i++] = e.getKey();
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        e.submit(put);
        e.submit(iterate);
        e.shutdown();

        start.countDown();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (list[i] == 0) {
                System.out.println("MAX i = " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: using JDK 7u11 and JDK 6u38 (64 bits version) on an x86 machine.

Comment: I would add a sleep to the `put` loop as well to ensure they are concurrent and one is not running to completion before the other one starts.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It does make it fail faster indeed. But I don't understand why the code I show behaves differently across versions. I would be interested to know if others observer the same.

Comment: @assylias Does it fail on Java 6 with the extra sleep?

Comment: I suspect `await()` isn't waking the threads as the same time on Java 6 as much as it does in Java 7.

Comment: The documentation specifies: "Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis."

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes I agree that both behaviours comply with the documentation (my introduction was a bit provocative) - I am questioning the change of behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we will look into `HashMap` sources and compare them between Java 6 and Java 7 we will see such interesting difference:

`transient volatile int modCount;` in Java6 and just `transient int modCount;` in Java7.

I'm sure that it is cause for different behavior of mentioned code due to this:

```
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

**UPD:** It seems to me, that this is a known Java 6/7 bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6625725 which was fixed in latest Java7.

**UPD-2:** Mr. @Renjith said, that he just tested and did not found any difference in behavior of HashMaps implementation. But I just tested it too.

My test was:

1. I have created `HashMap2` class, which is absolutely copy of `HashMap` **from Java 6**.

One important thing is we need to introduce here 2 new fields:

```
transient volatile Set<K>        keySet = null;
```

and

```
transient volatile Collection<V> values = null;
```

2. Then I used this `HashMap2` in test of this question and run it **under Java 7**

**Result:** it works like such test under `Java 6`, i.e. there isn't any `ConcurentModificationException`.

**That all proves my conjecture. Q.E.D.**

Comment: Interesting - but if anything, it should make java 6 fail faster due to the visibility guarantees of volatile, shouldn't it?

Comment: haha this is kind of sad because it probably slipped under the covers. I wonder how many people had problem with this without knowing.

Comment: I think no, because volatile introduces some kind of low performance of reading this fields value in comparison of this field without `volatile`. This leads to that fact, that one of your threads has time to iterate all its elements while another changes its state.

Comment: @assylias the problem is that the different threads will have `modCount` synchronized because of the `volatile`. So, none of them will ever see that are changing concurrently.

Comment: @assylias As I found later it is known Jaba 6/7 bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6625725

Comment: @Andremoniy The performance penalty due to volatile makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Tried simulating the problem with custom HashMap.But volatile modCount seems not making any difference.

Comment: @Andremoniy.. Using HashMap source and modifying the modCount

Comment: @Renjith I don't know HOW you actually simulate and do that trick, but I just now test it, by creating `HashMap2` with appropriate `volatile` fields - it works like `HashMap` under JDK7 - i.e. no `ConcurentException`.

Comment: @Andremoniy....Actually when I go for custom HashMap, it is not throwing any exception with and without volatile..I am perplexed:-)

Comment: @assylias, I don't understand, may be you are joking about performance :) But in any case, I just tested `HashMap` implementation under Java 7 - it works like in Java 6, i.e. there isn't `ConcurentModificationException`. See my UPD-2.

Comment: @Andremoniy No joke - the volatile penalty can be significant when running only 100 iterations (which is going to be super fast) and can in itself delay the threads and make them run sequentially instead of concurrently (basically what you said in an earlier comment). Increasing SIZE to 10000 for example makes the Java 6 code fail fast too because the penalty is not sufficient any more to prevent interleaving. That's my understanding of the phenomenon.

Comment: @assylias Ok, thanks. I'm glad that my understanding of this problem seems to be correct.

Comment: The performance difference between reading L1 cache data on the CPU and fetching from RAM can be a x30 factor or more.

Comment: @Andremoniy...Can you remove volatile from your custom hasmap class and run it under java 7?Ideally it should be throwing CME.

Comment: @Andremoniy I'll give a bit more time if you don't mind, in case somebody else wants to jump in.

Comment: @Renjith, my guess is that compiled "native" (in the figurative sense!!!) classes of Java, such `java.*` are working slightly faster, then clients classes. I could not prove it right now, but it seems to me, that it is true.

Comment: @assylias, volatile reads on x86 (or TSO sparc) are close to free - as simple as L1 cache hit. Volatile writes however are almost never cheap, they prevent reorder of the reads and require the CPU to flush its write buffers. Volatile reads *do not* hit the main RAM if they are found in L1. It's the cache-coherency protocol that takes care for.

Comment: @Andremoniy, yes HashMap does use intrinsics (what you call 'native').

Comment: @bestsss is it also true (cheap read) after a write on another cpu? I.e. is the cost of synchronizing  completely born by the write (which sounds inefficient if the write is never read)?

Comment: @bestsss thanks for the proof of my guess about intrinsics. Very interesting paper about this here: http://vanillajava.blogspot.ru/2012/11/java-intrinsics-and-performance.html

Comment: @assylias, if you have sharing/contention, writes are not cheap as there will be coherency traffic. How the cache line is updated (or evicted) depends on the cache coherency protocol and cache line state. The practical point is that volatile load is not that different than normal load on x86, it prevents hoisting and memory reorder but they all are compiler barriers, not hardware ones. However, HashMap should not be updated by another thread as the structure is not thread-safe/concurrent.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note, `ConcurrentModificationException` (despite the unfortunate name) is *not* intended to detect modification *across multiple threads*.  it is *only* intended to catch modifications within a single thread.  the effects of modifying a shared HashMap across multiple threads (without correct synchronization) are guaranteed to be broken regardless of the use of iterators or anything else.

In short, your test is bogus regardless of the jvm version and it is only "luck" that it does anything different at all.  for example, this test could throw NPE or some other "impossible" exception due to the HashMap internals being in an inconsistent state when viewed cross thread.

Comment: *your test is bogus regardless of the jvm version and it is only "luck" that it does anything different at all* - I 'm not agree. Please, read my answer; `HashMap`'s implementations are different in Java 6 and Java 7

Comment: @jtahlborn I am aware of the visibility issues in my test - the question was about the different behaviour across versions.

Comment: @assylias - please re-read my answer.  the behavior is completely and utterly _undefined_.  CME is never expected to work cross thread.  whether or not undefined behavior changes cross jvm version is mostly meaningless.

Comment: @Andremoniy - i'm not arguing that there is or is not a difference across the jvm versions, i'm explaining why that difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @jtahlborn I understand your point - it was a curiosity/practical question rather than a theoretical one. We agree that the code is fundamentally broken and its behaviour undefined.

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that on both Java 6&7, creating the iterator in the reader thread takes longer time than putting 100 entries in the writer thread, mainly because new classes have to be loaded and initialized (namely `EntrySet, AbstractSet, AbstractCollection, Set, EntryIterator, HashIterator, Iterator`)

So the writer thread has finished by the time this line is executed on the reader thread

```
    HashIterator() {
        expectedModCount = modCount;
        if (size > 0) { // advance to first entry
```

In Java 6, since `modCount` is `volatile`, the iterator sees the latest `modCount and size`, so the rest of iteration goes smoothly.

In Java 7, `modCount` is not volatile, the iterator probably sees stale `modCount=3, size=3`. After `sleep(1)`, the iterator sees updated `modCount`, and fails immediately.

Some flaws with this theory:

1. the theory should predict `MAX i=1` on java 7
2. before main() is executed, `HashMap` was probably iterated by other code, so the mentioned classes were probably loaded already.
3. reader thread seeing a stale `modCount` is possible, but not likely, since it's the first read of the variable on that thread; there's no prior cached value.

We may get to the bottom of this problem by planting logging code in Hashmap to find out what the reader thread is seeing.

Comment: Interesting theory. I have tried to add logging but it introduces some synchronization which changes the result.

Comment: can you not save log in a vanilla array, and dump it later? `expectedModCount=log[i++]=modCount`