# When is it appropriate to replace AtomicReference with a volatile member?

Tags: java, concurrency

If a class has a private `AtomicReference` member, and it only calls `AtomicReference#get` and `AtomicReference#set`, then is it (a) safe and (b) useful to replace that with a nullable `volatile` member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281163/1492106), if you will just be using the `get()` and `set()` methods, there is no real difference between the two.

Is it safe? Yes.

Is it useful? Debatable, considering what additional functionality you might need for the future. If you want to keep it as simple as possible, volatile might (arguably) offer slightly better readability. I generally stick to `AtomicReference` because I can't always predict future requirements and I don't much like changing variable types when it can be avoided.